# redirect_to hidden form field on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, redirect

I'm trying to understand how the `redirect_to` hidden form field works (on Wordpress), as in

`<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="http://www.mydomain.com/thank-you" \>`

Will it redirect to that value no matter what, or do I need to write some code including `wp_redirect()` code somewhere?

The reason I'm asking is: I have two forms, one with a `redirect_to` value to a page on my own site and one with a `redirect_to` pointing to an external domain. While the first works fine, the latter does not. It always takes me back to my front page. Thus, I'm trying to debug that problem.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Setting up redirect in hidden field does not redirect you anywhere . It just saves the value in that hidden field.

The Form redirects to the **url** you specify inside action attribute

i.e:

`<form action="http://example.com">`

If it's left empty or not written then it will redirect you to the same page by default , that's the reason that both of your forms redirect you to the same page.

If you want to redirect your other form to different url , specify it in your form action attribute.

EDIT :

Yes , If you use `wp_safe_redirect()` then it will redirect you back to your site , in case of providing external host as action attribute.

Comment: alright, it's `form action ="http://mydomain.com/wp-login.php?action=register&myarg=1` for the second form (which is not redirecting properly). The first form is nearly the same except without `myarg=1`.

Comment: I think it's because of `wp_safe_redirect` which does not allow redirecting to another host. Maybe you can add this to your answer, than it's complete ;)